# ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential_3 is incompatible with the layer: : expected min_ndim=4, found ndim=3. Full shape received: (None, 224, 256)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

I am new to Keras and I am attempting to create a CNN that takes a `(224,256,1)` sized image as an input.

Here is the error I keep getting:

```
    ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential_5 is incompatible with the layer: : expected min_ndim=4, found ndim=3. Full shape received: (None, 224, 256)
```

My interpretation of the error is that the data the layer got had 3 dimentions and the layer needs atleast 4 dimensions.  According to the keras [documentation](https://keras.io/api/layers/convolution_layers/convolution2d/), the input shape should be `(batch size, x , y , channels)`. I am only using a single image as I believe the batch size should just be `1`.

Here is the code for making the model:

```py
model = keras.Sequential([
                          keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=(3,3), activation="relu", padding='same', input_shape=(224,256,1), data_format='channels_last'),
                          keras.layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2), padding='same'), 
                          keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=(3,3), activation='relu', padding='same'),
                          keras.layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2), padding='same'), 
                          keras.layers.Flatten(),
                          keras.layers.Dense(8, activation="softmax")
])
```

Here is the prediction code:

```py
img = get_image()
img = convert_to_greyscale(img)
img = tf.expand_dims(img, axis=0) # add dimension to represent batch to the front
prediction = model.predict(img) # ValueError Input 0 of sequential_3 ...
```

let me know if you need anymore info, thanks!

Comment: You have to provide a four dimensional tensor, so you should expand dims also along dimension 3 (channel) to have a image size (1, X, Y, 1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `one dimension` to the image then `expand_dims` as `batch` like below: *(resize the image to the size of your model)*

```
from skimage import io
img = io.imread('1.jpeg', as_gray=True)[...,None]
img = tf.image.resize(img, [224, 256])
# ------------------------- ^^^  ^^^ this is size of your input model
img = tf.expand_dims(img, axis=0)
model.predict(img)
```

Output:

```
array([[0.1329774 , 0.1408476 , 0.13449876, 0.10563403, 0.11976303,
        0.12162709, 0.12393728, 0.12071485]], dtype=float32)
```